# How do I merge two csv files based on the words in a given list?

Tags: python, loops, csv, for-loop

I have two csv files, each of them are in this format,

```
file1
zip     name    score                
23431   david   12                  
23231   rob     45
33441   hary    23
98901   rgrg    55  


file2
zip1    name1   score1                
23433   david   12                  
23245   stel    45
33478   hary    23
98988   rob     55  
12121   jass    33
```

and I have a list that has the names, like this

```
lista = ['harry', 'rob', 'wine', 'david', 'jass']
```

The final csv file should look like this:

```
name    zip     score       zip1     score1
harry   x       x           x           x
rob     23231   45          98988       55
wine    x       x           x           x
david   23431   12          23433       12
jass    x       x           12121       33
```

that means, if any name from the list lies in either of the csv files, than we should include it in the new csv file along with its zip and score. Otherwise we should print 'x' in it.

This is what I have done so far:

```
import csv
with open('file1.csv', 'r') as input1, open('file2.csv', 'r') as input2, open('merge_final.csv', 'w') as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output)
    reader1 = csv.reader(input1)
    eader2 = csv.reader(input2)

    lista = ['harry', 'rob', 'wine', 'david', 'jass']
    writer.writerow(['name','zip','score','zip1','score'])

        for i in lista:     
            for row in list(reader1):
                rev = row[1]
                if i in rev:
                    score = row[2]
                    zip = row[0]    
                else:
                    score = 'x'
                    zip = 'x'               
            for row in list(reader2):
                rev = row[1]
                if i in rev:
                    score1 = row[2]
                    zip1 = row[0]
                else:
                    score1 = 'x'
                    zip1 = 'x'  
            writer.writerow([i, score, zip, score1, zip1])
```

This code is not working as expected. This is the output I got using this code.

```
name    zip     score       zip1     score1
harry   x       x           x           x
rob     x      x            x            x
wine    x       x           x           x
david   x       x           x           x
jass    x       x           x           x
```

Even thought there are many common words, only 'x' gets printed in the final merged csv file. I think the problem is with the loops. But, I don't seem to figure out the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the first call of `list(readerX)` exhausts the iterator that is the file handle.

Secondly, `rev` is supposed to be the `name` already, so check for equality not contains: `if name == rev`.

Thirdly, you'd mostly get 'x's except for the last names in each file since you iterate the files to the end and only the last row will really matter. You should `break` the inner loops *as soon as* you find a name, but set the default values only after you iterated the entire file *without* finding the name.

Also, it is very bad performance-wise to repeatedly iterate both files. You better load the two files into a permanent data structure with faster lookup like a nested `dict` with names as keys:

```
d1 = {row[1]: {'zip': row[0], 'score': row[2]} for row in reader1}
d2 = {row[1]: {'zip': row[0], 'score': row[2]} for row in reader2}
#   {'david': {'zip': 23431, 'score: 12, ...}    

for name in lista:
    if name in d1 or name in d2:
        writer.writerow([
            name,
            d1.get(name, {}).get('zip', 'x'),
            d1.get(name, {}).get('score', 'x'),
            d2.get(name, {}).get('zip', 'x'),
            d2.get(name, {}).get('score', 'x'),
        ])
```

To make your own approach work, change as follows, but note that this has terrible performance for larger data because of the nested loops:

```
# next(reader1)  # skip the header line if necessary
lst1 = list(reader1)  # load all the data into a list beforehand ...
for i in lista:  
    for row in lst1:  # ... that you can repeatedly iterate
        rev = row[1]
        if i == rev:  # compare for equality
            score = row[2]
            zip = row[0]   
            break  # <- you found the name, so end the loop! 
    else:  # note the indentation: this is a for-else-loop, not an if-else
        # the else-part is only executed if the for loop was NOT break'ed
        score = 'x'
        zip = 'x'
```

Comment: Thanks! 
Also, will you please point out the mistake(besides calling list(readerX))  in my above code? Just so that I can learn from my mistake and won't repeat the same again.

Comment: Thank you for your promptly reply. I also tried the code by using `if i == rev`, but the output didn't change(x was printed all over the file). Please allow me to ask one more question, I think the key to my problem is in this sentence **if a name is in neither file, then the zip and score variable from the previous iteration do not change and are written again...** how should I implement it ? Sorry, It hasn't been long since I started learning python.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you think it would be better to read the two files into a single nested dictionary where the names would be the keys and the values would be dictionaries with keys 'zip,'zip1','score' and 'score1'?

```
    {'hary' : 
        {'zip1':33478, 
         'zip':33441 ,
         'score':23,
         'score1':23 }
    }
```

Then iterate through the list and print 'x' for whatever the keys are not present

Answer (score 0):

The errors in above code:

1. The first loop of list(reader1) exhausts the iterator that is the file handle. So when the next iteration for 'lista' starts the reader1 is empty with len=0.
   Instead of repeatedly iterating the file handle store data in a list or dictionary.
2. When the i matches with rev in case of if(i in rev) you are continuing to iterate over rest of the file which causes the value of zip and score to be reset to 'x' as for the next iteration "i in rev" will give False. You need to remove the else part to rectify this. Instead declare zip,score as 'x' just after for i in lista: